# How to Lock a file and avoid readings while it's writing in C programing

Tags: c, file

I want to lock a file while writing no one should be able to read it. how to do it?.. please provide sample code.

Answer (score 3):

Do you use fopen? Then

[fopen](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fopen)

> x -
> Open the file exclusively (like the O_EXCL flag of open(2)). If the file already exists, fopen() fails, and sets errno to EEXIST. This flag is ignored for fdopen().